# Scene not rendered with 16-bit depth buffer on Android emulator

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I have a complex Android OpenGL ES2.0 app that works correctly, but I have run into an issue that I can't solve.

I was trying different `EGLConfig`s and I found out that part of the scene is not rendered when I choose an `EGLConfig` that has 16-bit depth buffer, although the whole scene is rendered correctly if I use a 24-bit depth buffer. I compared the `EGLConfigs` and couldn't find any differences between them other than the size of the depth buffer, the stencil buffer, which is 8-bit (and the ID, of course).

My first thought was that maybe it was a precision problem, but my near plane is at 2.0f, my far plane is at 25.0f and my objects are several units wide, so that can't be it.

Besides, I tried using different depth functions and, to my surprise, I discovered that if I use GL_GREATER the scene is rendered, although ordered incorrectly as expected. That ruled out precision completely.

I thought maybe the stencil buffer could be interfering somehow, although I don't use stencil testing at all. I tried explicitly disabling it but that produced no result.

This only occurs when I run my app on an AVD (in this case it is emulating a Nexus 7). I tried it on a real device and it worked correctly with both 16 and 24 bit buffers, but I want to make sure that it is a problem with the emulator.

What can be causing this behavior? I would really like to understand what is causing this and not force my app to request a 24-bit depth buffer if it is not necessary.

Comment: Long shot, but did you verify that you clear the depth buffer before each frame?

Comment: Yes, the depth buffer is `glClear`ed for each frame, and the render result is correct with a 24-bit depth buffer.

Comment: What GPU do you use to test it?

Comment: I test it on an Android virtual device, emulating a Nexus 7. GPU use is enabled and it works correctly if a choose a EGLConfig as previously described.

Comment: Emulator is known for it's crappy OpenGL ES funneling. In my case I get weird flickering and sometimes emulator crashing after running it for more than 10 minutes, but YMMV depending on what host OS/GPU/drivers you have. I suggest you to test OpenGL ES apps on real devices only.

Comment: Thank you keaukraine. I tested the app on an real device and could not reproduce this issue with any of the `EGLConfig`s that it offered, even though there were several with 16-bit depth buffers they worked beautifully. I will edit my question and leave it open in case someone has any other comments.